# Polymer noob - it seems that my unresolved does not turn into resolved once the document is ready

Tags: polymer

I am learning polymer and have started a simple document that just imports a font and has a single paragraph in the body. The body has the unresolved attribute.

When I test it, it seems that the unresolved never switches to resolved.

Help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>hello</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script src="../components/platform/platform.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="../components/font-gotham/gotham.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/consolidator.css">
    </head>

    <body unresolved touch-action="auto">
        <p>hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Note: when I remove the 'unresolved' attribute or apply it to the actual paragraph itself, the paragraph is correctly showing.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsbin.com/kefujiju/1/edit Is it possible you consolidator.css stylesheet is messing with the transition?

Answer (score 8):

`unresolved` is removed when Polymer initializes. Since you never load Polymer, `unresolved` never goes away.

Comment: Not your fault, IMO it's an easy mistake to make, a flaw in our system.